# d3.js donut chart select option onchange isn't updating the chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I have donut chart that's working fine except for it doesn't automatically update the chart when I select the option from drop down menu. so I have to refresh the page every-time after an option is changed from dorp down menu

following is code

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.outerRadius(radius - 10)
.innerRadius(radius - 70);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
 .sort(null)
 .value(function(d) { return d.population; });
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var loadData = function() {   
var metric = document.getElementById('metric').value;
 var dataFile = 'data_' + metric + '.csv'    
 d3.csv(dataFile, function(error, data) {

data.forEach(function(d) {
 d.population = +d.population;   
 });

var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
   .data(pie(data))       
   .enter().append("g")  
   .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
   .attr("d", arc)
   .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });

}); }
```

loadData()

can you please let me know what can be done to update the donut chart upon selection..
Thank you

Comment: Just a few checkpoints: * are you calling the loadData function when teh menu is clicked.
* I dont see you deleting the ".arc" in the loadData function, you need to clear the old dom elements when the loadData function is called with the new dataSet.

Comment: Please see this example for dynamic pie chart: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5872848